# How to show results of union query side by side?

Tags: mysql

I have two select statements with union and I wanna show the result in multiple columns or side by side.

I try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(emp.id) num1,dep.departmentname
from tblemployees emp
JOIN tbldepartments dep on dep.id = emp.OriginalDepartment
WHERE
emp.OriginalDepartment IN (208,168,209,189,157)
and emp.JobType in (41,51,52,53,54) 
AND emp.`Status`NOT IN (11,20,21,26,17) 
AND emp.retiredate > CURDATE()
GROUP BY dep.departmentname
union
SELECT COUNT(emp.id) num2,dep.departmentname
from tblemployees emp
JOIN tbldepartments dep on dep.id = emp.OriginalDepartment
WHERE
emp.OriginalDepartment IN (208,168,209,189,157)
and emp.JobType IN (1,6,7,8,9,11,26,32,33,34,36,43,45,46,47,48,49,55) 
AND emp.`Status`NOT IN (11,20,21,26,17) 
AND emp.retiredate > CURDATE()
GROUP BY dep.departmentname
the result show like this:
```

| num1 | departmentname |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | dep 2 |
| 5 | dep 3 |
| 20 | dep 4 |
| 50 | dep 5 |
| 53 | dep 2 |
| 56 | dep 3 |
| 30 | dep 4 |
| 16 | dep 5 |
| 19 | dep 6 |
| 40 | dep 7 |

and I wanna to show the results like this:

| num1 | num2 | departmentname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 53 | dep 2 |
| 5 | 56 | dep 3 |
| 20 | 30 | dep 4 |
| 50 | 16 | dep 5 |
|  | 19 | dep 6 |
|  | 40 | dep 7 |

Answer (score -1):

Conditionally aggregate instead

for example:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;

CREATE TABLE T
(dept VARCHAR(20),   type int);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
('one', 41),
('one', 41),
('one', 41),
('one', 41),
('two', 52),

('one', 1),
('one', 6),
('one', 1),
('two', 1),
('three', 6);

select dept, 
         sum(case when type in (41,52) then 1 else 0 end) num1,
         sum(case when type in (1,6) then 1 else 0 end) num2
from t
group by dept;

+-------+------+------+
| dept  | num1 | num2 |
+-------+------+------+
| one   |    4 |    3 |
| three |    0 |    1 |
| two   |    1 |    1 |
+-------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

need more help search for mysql pivot , still struggling publish REPRESENTATIVE sample data and desired outcome as text.